# Docx4J.toPDF throws PropertyException - No conversion defined

Tags: docx4j

I'm using commercial version of Doc4J, and I'm trying to convert a docx4j generated docx file to pdf using Docx4J.toPDF API. It fails with the below error.

How to fix this issue? Does this colour need to be in hexadecimal format? If so, is there any setting to generate it in hexadecimal format

```
org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException: null:3:14496: No conversion defined #black; property:'color'
    at org.apache.fop.fo.properties.PropertyMaker.make(PropertyMaker.java:446)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.PropertyList.convertAttributeToProperty(PropertyList.java:499)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.PropertyList.addAttributesToList(PropertyList.java:386)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FObj.processNode(FObj.java:127)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:293)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:179)
    at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:518)
    at org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil.serialize(XmlSerializerUtil.java:51)
    at org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil.serialize(XmlSerializerUtil.java:18)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:247)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:181)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:81)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:712)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:741)
```

Comment: I'm using XSL FO based PDF output with docx4j-export-fo module

Comment: I have resolved the issue, as I was setting the font color using docx4j somewhere as black, which I changed it to hexadecimal character 000000, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the docx file format, w:color/@w:val:

> This color may either be presented as a hex value (in RRGGBB format),
> or auto to allow a consumer to automatically determine the run color
> as appropriate.

Per http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/color_1.html